How do I allow requests from another site's iframe with Apache server?
I have a customer site, company.com, that loads a subdomain of our site into their iframe. Accessing sub.domain.com works, but not when it's loaded through their iframe.
I've tried adding header rules into my .conf file and .htaccess.
<Directory "/var/www/sub.domain.com">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from All
      AllowOverride All
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always append Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' https://company.com/;"

Then restarted the server etc/init.d/apache2 restart.
On company.com I get a blank status code (no 400 code), and in the transfer column it says NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Here's a picture:

